# Oscilloscope ground lead - BANG!

Tags: ground, oscilloscope, short-circuit

I just experienced a big bang caused apparently by a short through my oscilloscope's ground lead, and wanted to see if you could shed light on the *why* this happened.

Yes I have watched [Dave's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ) on the subject of scope ground leads, and was trying to be very careful. But obviously not careful enough. :-/

I was diagnosing a washing machine control board.  I wanted to view the tachometer output pin's status while in operation to see if it was working properly.

The tachometer (optical sensor) is powered by 13VDC, provided by an on-board power supply.

I connected the oscilloscope ground clip to the 13VDC ground.  This is indicated in the schematic below.
I connected the oscilloscope lead to the tachometer input pin.
I did not disconnect the connector from the control board, but instead piggybacked the scope probe and ground clip into the back of the connector.

When I plugged in the machine's 120VAC power cord, BANG went the washing machine's on-board power supply.  The bang was definitely more powerful than I would expect from 13VDC, and let the magic smoke out of several SMD components around the PSU.   The oscilloscope was not damaged.

I simply cannot figure out why this connection created a short circuit.  Even if the 13VDC ground was isolated from the chassis ground, why would it be at a high potential difference from chassis ground?  That would seem dangerous.

I tested the electrical outlet to ensure it's wired correctly.

Thanks for shedding any light on this.

Schematic: (full manual [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/925026/Whirlpool-Wtw4800xq.html?page=20#manual))
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the bang was caused by oscilloscope probing? Are you sure you couldn't cause some accidental short?

Comment: I was very careful and nothing else was unplugged or loose which could have caused this. Even if I had mistakenly connected the ground lead one pin left or right, it would have only been a 13vdc direct short if the chassis ground was connected to the 13vdc ground. I am quite confident this did not happen however. The amount of damage was way more than a tiny 13vdc power supply could inflict on itself.

Comment: One hint to be extra sure in the future: you don't want any current to flow through your scopes gnd. This would happen if there is a potential where you want to attach it. You can check what with a multimeter. Ac and DC.

Comment: Great jumping cats!  Went flipping through that service manual, and it appears that nothing in there is isolated from the mains.  Clipping your ground to just about anything inside would cause a short circuit with everything the mains can provide available to provide current for the bang.

Comment: Just thought of something.  You need to check your scope and the probd to see if they were damaged by the short.  Unplug the scope from power (remove batteries if it a portable unit) and use an ohmmeter to measure from the ground connection of the probe jack to the earth ground pin on the power cable.  If it is open,  DO NOT use that scope until it has been repaired.  Check the probe by measuring from the ground clip to the bnc ground - if open, replace the probe.  The entire current from the short passed through the ground of your scope, and could have burned traces or wires inside it.

Comment: Already checked that. Scope is fine. Probe is fine. Ground clip is directly connected to earth ground pin of power cable. Scope works fine also.  Why don't they put fuses on the ground lead for just this reason?

Comment: @RyanGriggs Fuses on the ground lead would mean the voltage in the even of a short can rise to lethal voltages, and if you then touch the bnc connector jack of your oscilloscope by accident (for example when you try to adjust the settings because you get weird results), you can get shocked by the bare metal

Answer (score 13):

Note that the 'ground' symbol on that 13V rail is NOT the same as the main safety ground symbol by the power cord.

Look at the whole wiring diagram and notice the two triacs a little lower down, if you are designing this thing you can save a couple of opto triacs by referencing the 13V line to the incoming live....

Get paranoid, a multimeter check would have saved you some SMPSU repair work.

Answer (score 11):

Always check the voltage between the ground scope lead and the circuit ground before making the connection.  If there is a non zero value, try reversing the AC plug on the scope OR on the circuit feed.  If both are three prong plus and thus you can't reverse either one, then you will need a 1:1 isolation transformer.  Good luck!