# Oscilloscope safety, measurements for safe probe ground connection

Tags: transformer, ground, oscilloscope, safety, short-circuit

I have several oscilloscope safety-related questions. The questions come after a bit of background information. Please let me know if you think there's something iffy with the background information. Most of the questions I have are about what multimeter measurements to do before connecting the oscilloscope ground to a point in the DUT's circuit. Sorry, the question is kind of long. I have seen some answers in the various questions on this site and others, including answers ([Oscilloscope ground lead - BANG!](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296140/oscilloscope-ground-lead-bang)) that recommend using a multimeter to check whether we are about to connect to ground or not. I'm asking about that specifically in question 5.

Connecting an oscilloscope's ground probe to something on the DUT that isn't at ground level is very bad, as that provides a short circuit to ground. This could fry our probes and/or the DUT and/or our oscilloscope, hence differential probes are used. I have one pair of differential probes, but my oscilloscope has two channels and I might have to use two channels at the same time depending on how the repair of the DUT goes. Then my single pair of differential probes won't help me, right?

1. I can't magically poke around with a probe on channel 2 without attaching its ground and get a meaningful signal just because I'm using a differential probe on channel 1, right?

Also, even if the DUT is isolated (through an isolation transformer or battery), if we attach the oscilloscope probe's ground clip to the DUT, the DUT now has the same ground as the oscilloscope, right?

2. Can the act of attaching the ground clip to an isolated device's ground be dangerous under certain circumstances? (Assuming we don't short stuff out by fumbling around too much.)
3. Should this only be done when the DUT is off? (other than to prevent fumbling around and producing shorts)
4. If we attach the second channel's probe ground in the wrong place after successfully connecting the first probe, we would again provide a short circuit to ground, correct?
5. Should I check with a multimeter if there is a voltage potential between the point I'm going to attach my probe's ground and my probe's ground? What if the potential is very low, e.g. 0.01V?
6. I think there's no 100% guarantee that something marked as ground in the schematics actually is ground. I would like to measure this in order to be 100% sure that the point in the circuit that I am going to connect to the probe's ground actually is ground. To do this, I would use a multimeter and poke around in the circuit, measuring voltages between points where I expect 5V/9V/12V and where I expect common ground (and look for a good large piece of metal at ground potential to connect the ground clip to). Any problems here?

Rumor has it that the power supply for my DUT (a vintage computer, Commodore VIC-20) (I don't have it nearby right now) is isolated, but I'd like to investigate whether that is true. The computer doesn't work and it's possible that it was isolated originally but is no more (could even be a replacement power supply for all I know.)
7) To check, as a first test I would unplug the power supply and check the resistance between pins that go into the wall and the pins that go into the computer, correct? My multimeter only checks up to 2 Megaohms. Is that enough? Are there any other tests I should do? Should I check for capacitance between the plug prongs and the pins that go into the computer? From what I've read, a few pF to a few thousand pF (probably depending on the size of the transformer) is normal? I just tested a random AC adapter that didn't show any kind of continuity between plug prongs and output pins and the result was 72 pF. That would yield a very high capacitive reactance of 44 MOhm at 50 Hz. (Note: only tested one combination of pins/prongs), and at 100V that would make for a couple microamps of leakage current, nothing to worry about, right?
(Note: The VIC-20 power supply is AC-AC 100V->9V. The remainder of the (linear) power supply circuitry is inside the computer.)

I was looking at isolation transformers and saw that UPS units are much cheaper than isolation transformers and might come in handy in plenty of other situations too (and can even be borrowed/rented).

8. Powering the DUT via the UPS (in battery mode, i.e. not connected to mains) isolates the DUT at least as well as an isolation transformer, correct?

Comment: Do I summarize correctly that you want to use your scope to measure a VIC-20 computer which has an isolated supply (it should have, if not, any metal parts of the VIC-20 would become **LIVE**) and you're worried about grounding? There should be no issue grounding the VIC-20 through the scope, unlike the "Oscilloscope ground lead - BANG!" question as there the circuit is mains live.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: Also there are a lot of "I do this and this, that's OK right?" confirmation type questions which can simply be answered yes/no but don't really need to because it looks like you already know the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to separate the subquestions into 3-4 question posts. Probably 1) general questions on how to probe (subquestions 1-6), 2) subquestion 7 and 3) subquestion 8. Thanks for the comments so far!

Comment: The VIC-20 has a two prong power supply, and the output is isolated (unless it has a serious issue), so in isolation you could connect the scope ground leads to any single point in the circuit to make measurements, but if the VIC-20 is say connected to a TV that already changes everything as the TV may be grounded itself, be grounded via other devices or antenna connections, so the safest place to connect scope probes is the 0V point called ground in VIC-20.

Comment: @Sneep:  A UPS is not really isolated.  Don't use a UPS in place of an isolation transformer.

Comment: @JRE - What if he unplugs it?  Is it not isolated then, if only until the battery dies?

Answer (score 1):

Your caution is admirable.
Is your oscilloscope probe's ground connection actually earth? In North America, your 'scope had better have a 3-prong AC chord, whose GND continues through AC wiring to an actual earth connection. Otherwise, touching metal parts of your 'scope could be hazardous to you because your entire 'scope is floating.

If you're satisfied that your 'scope is earth'd, you can easily probe a target VIC-20 device by probing **with no 'scope GND connection**. Ensure that your 'scope is set to measure DC, and its time scale can resolve 50/60 Hz signals. Vertical attenuator should be set to its highest scale.
[image: Probing finger with no 'scope probe GND connected]
You'll possibly see *some* 50/60 Hz stuff, even if your target VIC-20 is safely floating. It may even measure significant voltage. In some rooms, probing my floating finger has yielded 40V rms AC. When a floating DC supply was measured, a very similar waveform to that shown above was found. This is because your probe (1 Meg or perhaps 10 Meg) is like a voltage-probe antenna. But if you measure 120V (or 220V elsewhere), warning flags should fly "DANGER" - your DC supply isn't likely floating as it should.
 When you add a 10K resistor between probe tip and probe GND, does any AC voltage drop significantly? If so, you can be satisfied that current isn't going to be a shocking experience, and be somewhat more assured that your target VIC-20 is likely floating.
You shouldn't see any DC voltage if your target VIC-20 is truly floating. Probing its GND plane should show an average (mean) voltage near 0 V.

At this point, I'd try actually connecting 'scope probe GND to VIC-20 ground plane.

Note that you have a 50% chance of plugging a **faulty** target VIC-20 into a wall socket so that its **faulty** DC supply passes the previously described test. On another day, you may plug it in *the other way* and blow something up. Done that: my 'scope alligator didn't survive, but my blackened thumb did survive. So go through this test *every time* until you're assured that your DC supply floats entirely.

If your target VIC-20 has a 2-wire line chord, do the test with it plugged in *both* ways. And as Justme has pointed out, if you connect other stuff (like an unisolated-gnd TV) to your floating VIC-20, do this test *again*.